# How do I sort a Immutable map with specific keys order in scala?

Tags: scala

I have an immutable map :
Map("a1"-> "string1", "a2"->"string2", "a3"->"string3", "a4"->"string4")

How do I sort it in specific key order. Suppose keys are present in the order : List("a3", a2", "a4", "a1)

Desired output :
Map("a3"-> "string3", "a2"->"string2", "a4"->"string4", "a1"->"string1")

I tried to convert immutable map to a mutable LinkedHashMap which preserves the insertion order. But I am trying to write cleaner way to do it in scala, where I am storing keys in a specific order in a list and I want Map to be ordered in that specific key-order only.

Comment: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/SortedMap.html

Comment: @stefanobaghino Thank you :) New to scala and functional programming. Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap.html

Comment: @InsolentGoof Absolutely, no problem, cheers! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code snippet:

```scala
val m = Map("a1" -> "string1", "a2" -> "string2", "a3" -> "string3", "a4" -> "string4")
val o = List("a3", "a2", "a4", "a1")

val lm = ListMap(o.map(key => (key, m(key))): _*)
println(lm)
// ListMap(a3 -> string3, a2 -> string2, a4 -> string4, a1 -> string1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a good post that talks about [Scala immutable Map class: methods, examples, and syntax](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-immutable-map-class-methods-examples-syntax/) from `Alvin Alexander`. A map is just a data structure that have a collection of unique keys and each key is associated to a value. There are different implementations that you can use and also they are listed an explained in that post. For this case, using the `SortedMap` should be enough.

If you use the default implementation of a [Map](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.10/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html)

```scala
val map = Map(
  5 -> "5",
  2 -> "2",
  7 -> "7",
  3 -> "3",
  20 -> "20",
  12 -> "12",
  6 -> "6",
  13 -> "13",
  8 -> "8"
)
println("Map:")
map.foreach(println)
```

You will not be able to predict the order of the elements

```scala
Map:
(5,5)
(20,20)
(6,6)
(13,13)
(2,2)
(12,12)
(7,7)
(3,3)
(8,8)
```

If you use a [SortedMap](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.10/scala/collection/immutable/SortedMap.html)

```scala
val sortedMap = SortedMap(
  5 -> "5",
  2 -> "2",
  7 -> "7",
  3 -> "3",
  20 -> "20",
  12 -> "12",
  6 -> "6",
  13 -> "13",
  8 -> "8"
)
println("SortedMap:")
sortedMap.foreach(println)
```

the output will be the one you expect

```scala
SortedMap:
(2,2)
(3,3)
(5,5)
(6,6)
(7,7)
(8,8)
(12,12)
(13,13)
(20,20)
```

Also you can apply a custom order. The docs of `SortedMap` explains how

> An immutable map whose key-value pairs are sorted according to an
> [scala.math.Ordering](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.10/scala/math/Ordering.html) on the keys.
>
> Allows for range queries to be performed on its keys, and
> implementations must guarantee that traversal happens in sorted order,
> according to the map's [scala.math.Ordering](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.10/scala/math/Ordering.html).

Answer (score 0):

By default maps are essentially unordered data structures. You can try use [`ListMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap.html):

> This class implements immutable maps using a list-based data structure. List map iterators and traversal methods visit key-value pairs in the order they were first inserted.

> Entries are stored internally in reversed insertion order, which means the newest key is at the head of the list. As such, methods such as head and tail are O(n), while last and init are O(1). Other operations, such as inserting or removing entries, are also O(n), which makes this collection suitable only for a small number of elements.

```scala
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap
val map = Map("a1"-> "string1", "a2"->"string2", "a3"->"string3", "a4"->"string4")
val order = List("a3", "a2", "a4", "a1") 
    .zipWithIndex
    .toMap 
val ordered = ListMap(map.toSeq.sortBy(t => order(t._1)):_*)
println(ordered) // ListMap(a3 -> string3, a2 -> string2, a4 -> string4, a1 -> string1)
```